# Why does this create an infinite loop? - Codeacademy Js Course

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I am currently taking a basic Js course on Codeacademy and am testing out using a while loop scenario.
When I tried this (see code below), my browser tab crashed.
I assume this is because I have created an infinite loop.

Can anyone point out the problem to me?

```
var timeIs = 0

var addTime_1 = function(time){
    var newTime = time + 1;
    return newTime;
}

var addTimes = function(times){
    while (times<10){
        addTime_1(times)
    }
}


addTimes(timeIs)
```

Comment: You are never saving the changed value of `times`. You need to use `times = addTimes_1(times)` inside your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of *variable scoping*. And the purpose of the `return` keyword

`newTime` is a completely new variable, and `times` is not updated unless you explicitly tell it to be.

```
times = addTime_1(times);
```

Answer (score 0):

`addTime_1` doesn't actually change the value of `times`. It just returns the value that it is called with +1.

Since `times` is never set to anything new, it will remain 0 all the time.

And since 0 is less than 10 all the time, we have an infinite loop.

Edit:
Like others said, what is intended is most likely setting `times` to the value that is returned from `addTime_1`, i.e. `times = addTime_1(times)`

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using a for() loop in place of while() providing you know how many times your want your loop to run (in this example 10 times). This way you can have a bit more control over your loop since you choose how the loop increments itself.